# How to replace this regex with a empty using sed

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

For performance reasons I have to use sed to replace some text in a file and I just can't get it working. This is the search query (that works in C#) to be replaced:

```
<oTimer.*?/>
```

First off I can't seem to correctly escape the / i am using single quotes with double backslash so

```
<oTimer.*?\\/>
```

And then I get to the problem on how to replace this with a empty string.

```
sed 's/<oTimer.*?\\/g>
```

doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: That `sed` substitution expression should give you an error message as it does not contain a replacement part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If `<oTimer.*?/>` is your regexp, note that `<oTimer/>something else <anothertag?>` will also match. Is this desired? Maybe you are looking for an html parser instead?
- Are you sure about the question mark? It has no special meaning in basic regular expressions, so your pattern needs to end in (unusual) `?/>`
- You need a single backslash to escape the slash, but in this case it's easier to read using a different delimiter to your `s` command (you are free to choose one!): `s_regex_replacement with /_`
- If you want to replace with an empty string, you still need the third delimiter (the second and the third surround the replacement string, so for an empty replacement you have two delimiters with nothing in between).
- In total, I suspect you are looking for something like `sed 's_<oTimer[^>]*/>__g'`

Comment: `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`.

Comment: Not in basic regexp.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned C#.

Comment: He mentions `sed`, so I explain for `sed`.

Comment: Yup, the OP tries to emulate with `sed` the effect of C# matching `.*?`.  The problem is valid, his attempt at solving it isn't.

Comment: Nontheless is my answer correct. `sed` doesn't know about .NET regular expressions or `perl` regular expressions or some other, just basic regular expressions as defined in the POSIX standard. Strange to get a downvote for explaining all misconceptions in detail. )-:

Comment: The first two points in your answer show you're missing the point of the question.  Then the solution is not correct either, because it doesn't replace `<oTimer>/>`.  You're assuming tags, but the OP doesn't mention tags. _shrug_

Answer (score 1):

First, `sed` doesn't support non greedy quantifier `*?`.

Second, you should change the substitution operator's delimiter:

```
sed 's~<oTimer[^>]*/>~~g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` for this since it doesn't understand non-greedy matching. You can use `perl` instead:

```
perl -pe 's|<oTimer.*?/>||g' file.in > file.out
```

Or, to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|<oTimer.*?/>||g' file.in
```